# Problem moving application from DMG file

Tags: macos, dmg, vlc

I downloaded vlc-2.2.1.dmg to my computer and it opens ok.  When I try to copy the app to the Application folder I get this error message.  [image]

When I try to open VLC from the DMG file it runs fine.  I just can't move it to the application folder.  Any ideas why?  I am running OSX 10.6.  I thought i was because I didn't have trust applications from the internet turned on but that is not an option in 10.6
[image]

Comment: Validate the MD5 or SHA1 checksum of the vlc-2.2.1.dmg file. MD5: 744fc1aece233e19efa2d6d0adcfc9fd or SHA1: ac20bcdeb18fd21627fd2b08e7bcf295258ad513 and if it doesn't match then re-download the vlc-2.2.1.dmg file.

Comment: @user3439894 the OP says the VLC runs fine? so what would the checksum do ?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD, Anytime there is an issue with a downloaded file that there is a published checksum for then one the first steps on the diagnostic tree is to validate it against its published checksum. IMO The first step is to reboot the system and try reproducing the error and if it still errors out then validate the checksum.  If it doesn't match then re-download it and try again and validate again before doing anything else and go from there.  Also just because a given application might run from within the .dmg file doesn't mean something isn't corrupted or wrong with the .dmg file.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD, And since there is an error code 36 being thrown the diagnostic process has to start somewhere and validating checksums is an appropriate step.

Comment: @Paul, I downloaded vlc-2.2.1.dmg file and it copied and pasted as well as dragged and dropped fine.  The downloaded .dmg file also matched against its published checksums.  Did you validate it against its published checksum?

Comment: If you downloaded the VLC from here https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html then forget all the crap about Validating the MD5 or SHA1 checksum.. the source file is clean (I use it without problems.)

Comment: @Buscar웃SD, Validating against a checksum is not crap, they're published for good reasons and you saying so only shows lack of understanding that files can be download and be corrupted without being informed of the fact.  Many a time user has downloaded files, were told it was successful and it be corrupted and verified so by checksums. That said it only takes a few seconds to validate it so one can continue with a reasonable diagnostic process. I'm not saying the file is corrupt however with the issue at hand validating the file is not an unreasonable thing to rule out before continuing.

Comment: @user3439894 you need to talk to the OP about running the validation. You could enlighten me how the OP gets a corrupt file from same source as you and me ?

Comment: When I try and move the VLC file from the DMG file I still get the error message  but I see a 12kb file in the app folder with a greyed out circle for the icon.

Comment: @Paul, Have you validated the downloaded vlc-2.2.1.dmg file against one of it's published checksums yet and if not why not?

Comment: My system has been shutting down frequently and displays a message that it had to shut down and I lose all my work.  I think once I figure out this problem that my dmg file will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

After you download the VLC.dmg, you double click on it to create a installer and it opens new window that looks like this.

[image: vlc]

Now just "drag" the VLC.app icon to the Application folder.

Alternatively, copy the VLC.app to the desktop and then move it to the Applications folder.

There are some reports regarding the Finder Error -36.

Try the "dot clean" as described here http://osxdaily.com/2015/02/21/fix-error-code-36-finder-mac-os-x/

and explained here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dot_clean.1.html

Comment: 1. He already has the .dmg file opened. 2. By default one will not see the .app extension as shown in your picture when the .dmg file is opened. 3. It doesn't make any difference, it can be copied and pasted or dragged and dropped!

Comment: @user3439894 I am showing what happens when I click on the VLC dmg file

Comment: I see the same thing that is in this image.  I cannot copy and paste it or drag it to the Application folder.  It runs just fine when I double click and open it.

Comment: @Paul, By default the .app is hidden, as well as many others, and the advanced Finder preference **[] Show all filename extensions** is unchecked and therefore when images are posted for technical support purposes it should be so noted so as to avoid confusion.  Not all users check that preference and I've seen many a post in this same context when a user will say e.g. "_I don't see that on my system_" etc.  As to not being able to c&p or d&d yet run the .app bundle from within the .dmg file nonetheless the issue needs to be troubleshot and I've already commented under your question on this.

Comment: It would not harm if you repair the disk permissions (in the Disk utility). Is it VLC the only app you have problems with ?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD, The **vlc-2.2.1.dmg** file is a **Read Only** _disk image file_, so running `dot_clean` on it will have no affect on it and IMO makes the added links to your answer irrelevant.  Validating against it published checksum is what should be done first and take it from there so we know whether or not we're dealing with a valid .dmg file or not.  There is also a possibility that a portion of the file was written to a failing sector if it's on a rotational hard drive however validating the image is the easiest and appropriate step to start the diagnostic process.

Comment: Buscar, I have tried dragging the VLC.app file to the application folder and the download folder but both give me the error 36.  I will try the dot_clean command,

Comment: Good luck, hope it works for you.

Comment: So far I have tried dot_clean and repair permissions and I still have the problem.